# Alternative to Javascript prompt box for younger users

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Can anyone can suggest an alternative to Javascript prompt box that is better for young users?

```
prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");
```

[Check it out.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt)

Since the input box needs to be designed for children, I want the prompt box to be more colorful and lively. Any suggested existing box that I can use?

The requirement is that I have to let the user enter a string, receiving it.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the jQuery UI library?

Here you can see an example of a [modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

You can modify the styles or select from different themes.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried out [BootBox](http://bootboxjs.com/)?

> Bootbox.js is a small JavaScript library which allows you to create
>   programmatic dialog boxes using Twitter’s Bootstrap modals, without
>   having to worry about creating, managing or removing any of the
>   required DOM elements or JS event handlers.

It has a very neat alternative to the default JavaScript Prompt box.

Comment: Note that all current versions of bootbox are affected by an advisory: https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/882/versions

Answer (score 2):

I find the browser's prompt (, confirm and delete) boxes ***extremely*** annoying.

Partly to solve this problem, I've written iocream.js. It's a sample wrapper around the DOM with two text-input methods: `jin` (read like C++ ' s `cin`) and `jinarea`.

You can find the docs at [this bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/sumukhbarve/iocream), and examples [here](http://iocream.blogspot.in/2013/12/bisection-method-solving-polynomial.html).

Hope I helped.

**EDIT:**
I've posted a similar answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437147/javascript-prompt-alternative/20584996#20584996)

Answer (score 1):

the Jquery UI one's good:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

A jquery plugin named [Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php) gives you a lot of options not only for prompts but also for alerts and confirm boxes

Answer (score 0):

qtip2 is another nice free javascript library http://qtip2.com/