# Alternative to window.prompt, not working in webkit browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any alternative to a pop up dialog box with a text box with OK and cancel button.

I tried window.prompt but its not working on my custom defined webkit browser but working on Mozilla and others.

```
   function Add() {

        var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/;
        var newName = window.prompt("New Recipe");
        //Check for alphanumeric and 2 special charaters
        if(!reg.test(newName)) {
            window.alert("only alpha numeric"); 
            return false; 
        }
        if((reg.test(" "))||(newName.length == 0)) {
            return false;
        }
 }
```

Comment: What webkit browser are you using? What is in `window` if you type it in console? Have you tried just `prompt()` ?

Comment: What is your "custom defined webkit browser"?

Comment: this has been asked before, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905294/alternative-to-javascript-prompt-box