# Proper Way to receive number Input From User - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, prompt

I created the webpage where is the google map, and every user can input some data. The user just clicks on the map and the marker on map appears.

Now I would like to get the number from the user and place it just under the marker.

It's working, but I'm getting data by:

```
prompt();
```

But I find this way as horrible and bad looking for the user. The user can also disable the prompts in a browser. Also on the mobile prompt() looks awful. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't mind using bootstrap, might be worthwhile to look into [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: You can use modals without bootstrap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular HTML `<form>` on the page and then override the form submit to pass data into your javascript instead of refreshing the page.

If you're using jQuery, here is a helpful API to get you started. https://api.jquery.com/category/forms/

Here are some other options: [Alternative to Javascript prompt box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905294/alternative-to-javascript-prompt-box)