# Weird JavaScript return box

Tags: javascript, ios, fonts, mobile-safari

I'm building a webpage for a basic voting system for a nearby motorbike club and meet.

Everything was going fine until only one device displayed the alert text in a strange format. In iOS with a large font it overlaps the text and fades the edges of the alert. Can't post image without ten reputation but if you can find a way for me to show I will.

What I'm looking for is a solution so those on the day who have the same setup can view the page correctly.

The code for the alertbox is simple.

```
OnSubmit="return validate(this);"
```

And in the header

```
Function validate(form){ Return confirm("text here"); }
```

This was typed on a mobile device so forgive any typos or mistakes. Any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `confirm()` box that renders differently depending on device and browser.

Here's another thread dealing with the same issue: [Alternative to Javascript prompt box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905294/alternative-to-javascript-prompt-box)

If you prefer a drop-in solution you can use this library here: http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: Is there anyway to make the default box render correctly

Comment: You can't really control it, since the browser and device determines what it looks like. If you want control over its appearance, you'll have to use a library such as the one above, or this one http://github.hubspot.com/vex/ (which is very easy to use)